# How can the Feeds module be made to retrieve all items or items a few years old?

Tags: feeds

I am creating a planet style aggregation website and when I add a feed, the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module limits the age of the articles to those less than 3 months or so. But when I use the aggregator module all the articles from the feed are included.

This feature in Feeds appears to be hard wired, as I suspect the aggregator module depends on Feeds too. Is there a way to patch feeds to remove this limitation?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: @googletorp - The feature/problem is present on Drupal 6 and 7 alike. I have started using Drupal 7 now